# Trigger StackPanel Mouse Event programmatically

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I have the stackpanel with PreviewMouseUp event. Actually i need to trigger(call stackPanelMouseUp()) the mouseup event by programmatically ( That means without performing the mouse down operation on StackPanel)

```
stackPnl.PreviewMouseUp += stackPanelMouseUp;

  private void stackPanelMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
}
```

Thanks,

Sowndaiyan

Comment: I got the answer thanks,
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
 stackPnl.PreviewMouseUp += stackPanelMouseDown;
 int timestamp = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks).Milliseconds;
  MouseButton mouseButton = MouseButton.Left;

MouseButtonEventArgs mouseClickEvent = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, timestamp, mouseButton); mouseClickEvent.RoutedEvent = StackPanel.PreviewMouseUpEvent;
                            mouseClickEvent.Source = stackPnl;

                            stackPnl.RaiseEvent(mouseClickEvent);
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>